# Why Postgresql doesn't match string?

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, insert

When  i insert values to postgres table, i found an obvious error 'syntax error at or near "WHERE"'. But when I start to research this error, I meet a strange behavior of strings.

[image: screen of strange behavior]

One of values is string (character varying), and when I add another one the Postgres and any other editor doesn't match this as string, even if it inside of quotes.

[image: screen of another editor]

Why? this is url to facebook, and it is valid, when I go to this link. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Postgres does not change the values you send it. So it's most probably your application that somehow encodes this value **before** sending it to the database. You need to show us the part of your application that inserts the data.

Comment: Question is closed, the reason is because of it is match only 10 000 symbols in one string, in order to match more you should '\n', thanks every one)